# Java Custom Button (not JButton) Problems

Tags: java, swing, button, mouselistener

Ok, so, what I've been trying to figure out is how I can make a custom MouseListener for all my buttons that would not require listing every single one of them in the Handler, because I'm going to have a lot of them. Here's the code I have in my Listener as of now:

package com.dinobuilding.handler;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import com.BLANK.BLANKScreen;
import com.BLANK.BLANKWindow;
import com.BLANK.menufeature.Button;

public class ButtonHandler implements MouseListener {

public BLANKWindow dbw;
public BLANK Screen dbs;

static Button button = new Button();

public int buttonX = button.x;
public int buttonY = button.y;
public int buttonSizeX = button.xSize;
public int buttonSizeY = button.ySize;

public ButtonHandler(BLANKWindow dbw, BLANKScreen dbs) {
    this.dbw = dbw;
    this.dbs = dbs;
}

public static void setButton(Button b) {
    button = b;
}

public int mouseEventX;
public int mouseEventY;

Graphics g;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseEventX = e.getLocationOnScreen().x;
    mouseEventY = e.getLocationOnScreen().y;

    if(mouseEventX <= buttonX && mouseEventX >= buttonX + buttonSizeX) {
        if(mouseEventY <= buttonY && mouseEventY >= buttonY + buttonSizeY) {
            button.onClicked(dbs, dbw, g);
        }
    }
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}
```

And here's the code in the first button that I'm trying to implement:

```
package com.BLANK.menus;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import com.BLANK.BLANKScreen;
import com.BLANK.BLANKWindow;
import com.BLANK.handler.ButtonHandler;
import com.BLANK.menufeature.Button;

public class MainMenuPlayButton extends Button {

public static int x;
public static int y;
public static int xSize;
public static int ySize;
public static String s;
public static Graphics g;

public MainMenuPlayButton(int x, int y, int xSize, int ySize, String s, Graphics g) {
    super(x, y, xSize, ySize, s, g);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xSize = xSize;
    this.ySize = ySize;
    this.s = s;
    this.g = g;
    setColor(new Color(0, 226, 26));
    draw();
}

public MainMenuPlayButton() {

}

public static void draw() {
    drawButton(x, y, xSize, ySize, g, s);
    ButtonHandler.setButton(new MainMenuPlayButton());
}

public void onClicked(BLANKScreen dbs, BLANKWindow dbw, Graphics g) {
    setColor(new Color(216, 0, 0));
}
```

I think my main problem is that the code in the ButtonHandler gets called before the code in the Button class and therefore the ButtonHandler is utilizing the Button class itself, not the MainMenuPlayButton class. If you need the Button class as well, simply tell me, however I can't imagine why. Thank you in advance!

---

**Edit**

Ok, after debugging some, I have found that I in fact have the opposite problem. The button is never being clicked. The `getSource()` method could work, however I don't really know how to use that and I don't think that I could use that without hardcoding every single button, which is really something I do not want to do.

**EDIT 1**:
Do you think maybe I could do use the MouseEvent's `getX` or `getXOnScreen`? By the way, I registered the ButtonHandler using frame.addMouseListener on my JFrame, so...

**EDIT 2**:
It would seem that the `getX` method does not work either. If you could help me on that, I would very much appreciate that.

Comment: Each specific class of button will want to have its own Handler object added to it. For instance, if this were a calculator program, I'd make one handler for the numeric buttons and another one for the math operations buttons, and perhaps a 3rd for GUI functions such as to exit. Also, you can get the source object for the mouse press via the MouseEvent's `getSource()` method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have an overall super Button class that I want all Buttons to use, and the ButtonHandler utilizes that. Also, the Mouse itself is not my problem, my problem is that I can't get the ButtonHandler to change which Button's onClicked method is being called, or, more specifically, I can't get the setButton method to work.

Comment: You may need to do some more debugging to see exactly what and where its failing.

Comment: why the static objects?

Comment: @tgkprog because I use the static objects in a different class that requires that I make them static.

Comment: Lord: that's not a reason to use static anything. You would pass around references instead which would give your code much greater flexibility and **testability** including use of interfaces, mocking, and unit testing. Given this new information, I get a stronger feeling that your program may benefit from a re-write from the ground up. I've done this on several of my projects -- completely re-written them after finding out that their overall structure is faulty, and it often *is* worth it.

Comment: Edit: or use dependency injection as a way to link objects without resorting to static fields. This isn't a MineSweeper type program by chance is it?

Comment: OK, or it may not be all that important to you any more.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the object that was pressed and tripped the MouseListener, use the MouseEvent's getSource() method. For example, this *might* work:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    (YourButton) button = (YourButton) e.getSource();
    button.onClicked(...);

}
```

Other bits:

- Rename your class from Button to something else, since the Button name clashes with the java.awt.Button class, and this can cause difficult to debug errors.
- I cringe any time I see a Graphics field declared in a class, as it suggests possible inappropriate painting. Make sure that you really know what you're doing if you ever use one of these as a field since it's easy to get image loss or a NullPointerException if not used correctly, since the Graphics object is frequently changed by Java, and this change is completely out of your (the programmer's) control. Don't say that you haven't been warned.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your comments:

> Yes, I do know what I'm doing with the Graphics field, however, if it makes you feel better, know that it's only temporary and I will be changing it to something else later.

OK, I've just been burned on this before. As long as you get it from a BufferedImage and don't try to get it by calling getGraphics() on a component or by pulling it out of a paint or paintComponent method, then you might be OK.

---

> Also, I'm pretty sure that I'm getting the object it clicked correctly, but I can't get it to access the correct subclass of Button. It's only getting the Button class itself, not the MainMenuPlayButton.

Sorry, but this doesn't make sense since you don't get "classes" when you obtain a reference, an object pure and simple, and in fact you would get the very same object that the ButtonListener was added to and that tripped the listener, and the class of this reference will be whatever class your button is. I am assuming that you're adding your MouseListener directly to your "Button" object, correct? Again, time to do some debugging.

---

**Edit 2**
Regarding the most recent edit to your question:

> Ok, after debugging some, I have found that I in fact have the opposite problem. The button is never being clicked. The getSource() method could work, however I don't really know how to use that and I don't think that I could use that without hardcoding every single button, which is really something I do not want to do.

No, there is no need to hard-code each button, trust me. That's the whole reason for using listeners that are added to the buttons.

> EDIT 1: Do you think maybe I could do use the MouseEvent's getX or getXOnScreen? By the way, I registered the ButtonHandler using frame.addMouseListener on my JFrame, so... the

There's one of your problems. If you want to listen to your buttons, you're going to want to be able to register listeners on the button itself. If you have an array or collection of them registering listeners is easy. And no, I don't recommend using x and y on screen since it makes your program **extremely** fragile. If you did this, any changes to the structure of your GUI would require subsequent hard-code changes to your x and y handling. Ugh.

This begs the question of why create your own Button class, and why not instead use JButtons or a subclass of JButtons. You appear to be re-inventing the wheel, but (sorry to be blunt) creating one that is square.

---

**Edit 3**

> But you cast the variable to a button, meaning that if I have multiple buttons I have to cast each and every one of them to a different thing.

No absolutely not as the magic of polymorphism should work here. But they're objects of the same type, no? Or do you have many different subclasses of your Button class? And regardless, inside of the `mouseClicked(...)` method, you appear to want to call only one method on your button, `onClicked(...)`, which I imagine has to be an object of the super class, right? So by calling this method on the current button, It should call its own correct code.

> The problem I have with JButton is that they already exist. I can't edit them and I can't customize them, ...

This is patently not true. You can change their appearance and behaviors by many means, including by subclassing or by a factory creation method. Plus they already come with the machinery for being able to register listeners and respond to mouse actions.

> ...Also, would I have to register/make a new handler for each and every one of the buttons?

Again, you appear to be forgetting that polymorphism should take care of all of this. One handler **should** do, depending on how well-behaved your code is.

> I am going to have a LOT of buttons, and I don't think that that would be a viable solution. If not the `getX` how would I get it to do something when the thing is clicked?

I've given you my recommendation, other than sometimes it is better to re-write sections of code if the design can be improved, meaning again you may want to consider retrofitting your code to use JButtons.

Comment: Yes, I do know what I'm doing with the Graphics field, however, if it makes you feel better, know that it's only temporary and I will be changing it to something else later.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that I'm getting the object it clicked correctly, but I can't get it to access the correct subclass of Button. It's only getting the Button class itself, not the MainMenuPlayButton.

Comment: But you cast the variable to a button, meaning that if I have multiple buttons I have to cast each and every one of them to a different thing. The problem I have with JButton is that they already exist. I can't edit them and I can't customize them, and therefore I don't want to use them. Also, would I have to register/make a new handler for each and every one of the buttons? I am going to have a LOT of buttons, and I don't think that that would be a viable solution. If not the <code>getX</code> how would I get it to do something when the thing is clicked?

Comment: @LordMastodon: what kind of program are you trying to create by the way?